# difference bewteen <jndi-name> and <local-jndi-name> in Jboss.xml?

Tags: jndi, jboss5.x, ejb-2.x

I am new to EJB and trying to run some EJB (2.0) examples in Jboss 5. The execution is ok, but I found in the jboss.xml these lines:

```
<jboss>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>MyStatelessBean</ejb-name>
            <jndi-name>JNDIName</jndi-name>
            <local-jndi-name>LocalJNDIName</local-jndi-name>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</jboss>
```

I have tried to google but cannot find the explanation of the distinct between `<jndi-name>` and `<local-jndi-name>`, While in the code, the author only used the name defined in `<jndi-name>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJB 2.x beans have both Remote and Local interfaces. The `<jndi-name>` element is for binding the Remote interface, while `<local-jndi-name>` is for binding the local interface.

The reason the naming is inconsistent is that EJB 1.x only had remote interfaces, so only `<jndi-name>` was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can find documentation in the `docs` directory of JBoss distribution  `docs/schema/jboss_5_0.xsd`.

These element is the define as the `local-jndi-nameType` type and here is description for it:

> The JNDI name under with the local interface should be bound. If it is not
>   provided jboss will assume "jndi-name" = "beanClass/local"